# Aggregations with dependent conditions on mongoDB

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I want to find those patients who he/she had got **nose allergic**  then got **nose cancer**.

So the following data should return the user **Jack**.

Only **Jack** meets the query conditions.

Please give me some similar queries are similar to this kind of problem. Thanks so much

## Sample data

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Mary",
    "symptoms": "nose allerge",
    "datetime": "2011-04-02"
},

{
    "id": 2,
    "name": "Jack",
    "symptoms": "nose allerge",
    "datetime": "2011-04-02"
},

{
    "id": 3,
    "name": "Mark",
    "symptoms": "nose allerge",
    "datetime": "2010-01-02"
},

....


{
    "id": 4,
    "name": "Jack",
    "symptoms": "nose cancer",    
    "datetime": "2015-04-09"
},

{
    "id": 5,
    "name": "Mary",
    "symptoms": "nose cancer",    
    "datetime": "2010-09-02"
},
```

Comment: @Michael Mary will not match because the date she was diagnosed with nose cancer was before the nose allerge, not after.

Comment: @chridam thanks for your further explaination

Answer (score 2):

Try the following aggregation pipeline which first filters documents on the two symptoms in question, then sorts the resulting documents in the next pipeline by `datetime` descending which can then be grouped by name and get those ordered symptoms pushed to an array `diagnosis`. You then further filter the resulting documents from the previous grouping pipeline by matching on the first diagnosis array element that has value `"nose cancer"` because that should be the latest symptom and with then second element being `"nose allerge"`. You finally have your patient through **`$project`** operation:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    {
        $match: {
            symptoms: { $in: ["nose allerge", "nose cancer"] }
        }
    },
    {
        $sort: { datetime: -1 }
    },/**/
    {
        $group: {
            _id: "$name",
            "diagnosis": { 
                "$push": "$symptoms" 
             }
        }
    },
    {
        $match: {
            "diagnosis.0": "nose cancer",
            "diagnosis.1": "nose allerge"
        }
    },
    {
        $project: {
            name: "$_id",
            symptoms: "$diagnosis",
            _id: 0
        }
    }
])
```

Result:

```
{
    "result" : [ 
        {
            "name" : "Jack",
            "symptoms" : [ 
                "nose cancer", 
                "nose allerge"
            ]
        }
    ],
    "ok" : 1.0000000000000000
}
```